# How to add order for appending in svg D3

Tags: jquery, d3.js, svg, jquery-svg

I am using d3 charts.

```
var svg = container.append('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .on("click", hideDiv).append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    d3.select("svg").append("rect").attr("width", '100%').attr("height", '100%').attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");
```

This is my code. while running this code in the chart is not drawing. But in console when move "rect" before g the chart will draw.
 in console before move rect the code will be

```
<svg width="2200" height="2690"><g transform="translate(120,20)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(180,1421.327880859375)"></g>3
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
```

But after move rect is,

```
<svg width="2200" height="2690">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
<g transform="translate(120,20)"></g>
```

I want like this. Please help me. I'm stucked with this.

Comment: Instead of append, you can use insert, end use a selector for the element before which you want to insert

Comment: @HuguesStefanski  i want like this.. if it happens graph will draw otherwise not.<svg width="2200" height="2690">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
<g transform="translate(120,20)"></g>

Comment: Try something like d3.select("svg").insert("rect","g").attr("width", '100%').attr("height", '100%').attr("fill", "#FFFFFF");

Comment: @HuguesStefanski it doesn't work.. what i have to do

Comment: Could you maybe set a jsfiddle or plnkr to ease the process? This would allow to check your code more easily

Answer (score 0):

Your D3 code is working for me, you are using  #FFFFFF ( white ) to fill your rect, if you are not filling the container then it will default to white and the rect wont show, try to use a different color
Same applies to the two svg elements, if you change colors they will both display

Note also, you already created an svg variable, so you do not need to select it again to append the rect, append directly:

```
svg.append("rect")...
```

here is a working jsfiddle demo with rect set to yellow color:

```
.attr("fill", "#FFFF00");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs3sfo62/27/)

Comment: Iam getting like this

<svg width="2200" height="2690"><g transform="translate(120,20)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(180,1421.327880859375)"></g>3
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
 
Here the chart is not drawing. When i make rearrange the code in console like

<svg width="2200" height="2690">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
<g transform="translate(120,20)"></g>

The chart is drawing no issues. how can i made it?

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle to include the svg elements, you have typos, why do you have 3 between </g>3</rect> in the first <svg>?. you're also not closing the </g></svg> at the end. both SVG elements show fine in the jsfiddle, please take a look

Comment: I am getting this when i run my code

<svg width="2200" height="2690"><g transform="translate(120,20)">
<g class="node" transform="translate(180,1421.327880859375)"></g>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>


 i dont get chart while running this. But when move 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
to as s asecond line the chart will draw. ie

<svg width="2200" height="2690">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#FFFFFF"></rect>
<g transform="translate(120,20)"></g>

Comment: The only difference between the 2 <svg> elements, is that in the second, you are moving it out of the <g> element, so the transform (translate) will not be applied to it. if you translate the <rect> a value bigger than its container then it will go out of bounds and disappear, but your <svg> height/width are big enough so that shouldn't be the problem. is the <svg> included in another container? At this point we need to see more of your code to help you out, as I pointed, the jsfiddle link in my answer shows both <svg> elements exactly as yours, I only changed colors for demonstration.